# Inequality with two absolute values: $ |x-3|-|x-4|<x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm new here, and I was wondering if any of you could help me out with this little problem that is already getting on my nerves since I've been trying to solve it for hours.

Studying for my next test on inequalities with absolute values, I found this one:

$$ |x-3|-|x-4|<x $$
(I precisely found the above inequality on this website, [here to be precise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26564/solving-inequality-with-two-absolute-values), but, the problem is that when I try to solve it, my answer won't be $(-1,+\infty)$, but $(1,7)$. I took the same  inequalities that the asker's teacher had given to him and then put them on a number line, and my result was definitely not $(-1,+\infty)$

Here are the inequalities: 
$$ x−3 < x−4 +x $$ 
$$ x−3 < −(x−4) +x $$
$$ −(x−3)<−(x−4)+x $$

And here are my answers respectively:
$$ x>1, \quad x>-1, \quad x<7 $$

I will really appreciate if anyone could help me out, because I'm already stressed dealing with this problem, that by the way, it is not demanding that I solve it, but you know, why not?

Comment: of course you need to think about how to understand this for yourself, but it is nice to have some assurance from an impartial third party... check out http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=|x-3|-|x-4|%3Cx

Comment: You can do this by discussing several cases, try to have a look at similar problems, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26564/solving-inequality-with-two-absolute-values and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98157/how-could-we-solve-x-in-x1-1-x-2/

Comment: Another possibility is trying to do this graphically. $|x-3|-|x-4|$ is the difference between the distance from $x$ to 3 and the distance from $x$ to 4. If you try to think about this (geometrically, looking at points on the real line), you will find out that the graph of this function is very simple: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=|x-3|-|x-4|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is almost correct, the last step is to restrict your solution to the corresponding region.

For example, for $x>1$, the answer must be in the $x>4$ region, so your answer for this region is $x>4$.

For $x>-1$, your answer must be in $x<3$ region, so your answer for this region is $-1<x<3$.

And for the last one, $x<7$, your answer must be in the corresponding region we had first, namely $3<x<4$, so your answer for this region is $3<x<4$.

Now draw these three answers on the number line and you'll have $x>-1$, the desired final answer.

Comment: I totally appreciate this, so simple but effective. Now I do understand, and blame myself how could I not see this before.

Comment: @user38807: Glad to hear that.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, my curiosity is driving me crazy. It is demanding to restrict the solution in every problem? Or in which cases, because I have one problem where, if I restrict the solution to the regions, it won't work.

Comment: @user38807: Well, when you have multiple absolute values and you want to get rid of them, you'll have to assume where the term in the absolute sign is negative and where it is positive and you'll have to check your final answers with those primary assumption whether they are within that region or not.

Comment: Feel free to share your other problem with me, so we can check if it works out to what you're told.

Comment: I don't know if it's against rules to post it here, (if so I'm sorry), but: |3-2x|<|x+4| (I already did this one by another method) but when I use the method you used before, I get (-∞,∞). Tell me if I'm wrong, the regions I analysed were (-∞,-4)(-4,3/2)(3/2,∞) and the answers were respectively: x<-1/3 , x<7 and x>-1/3. Restricting those answers to the regions, I got (-∞,4),(-4,3/2) and (3/2,∞). Once again, I must be doing something wrong or making up something.

Comment: I got the right answer when I put the answers before restricting them to the regions on the number line. But after restricting them, I got (-∞,∞). So that's what I was asking earlier, when should I restrict the answers, if in one problem I got it right, but then in another, I got it wrong?

Comment: Let's discuss your other problem in chat.

Comment: It says I don't have enough reputation to chat. Any other way?

Comment: Oh, dear. That's unfortunate. OK, I got $-\frac 13 <x<\frac 32$ but I am not sure since I didn't double-check the answer. The only one you got wrong is probably $x<-\frac 13$ which is supposed to be $x>7$ on the restricted region of $x<-4$, maybe check that part in your answer sheet?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4643/discussion-between-gigili-and-chairotp)

Answer (score 14):

How to solve $|x-3|-|x-4|<x$? Let $f(x)=|x-3|-|x-4|$

I would begin by noting $|x-3|=x-3$ for $x \geq 3$ whereas $|x-3|=3-x$ for $x \leq 3$.
Likewise, $|x-4|=x-4$ for $x \geq 4$ whereas $|x-4|=4-x$ for $x \leq 4$

1. if $x \geq 4$ then $x > 3$ hence $f(x)=x-3-(x-4)=1$ and we find $1<x$ which is true in this case. This puts $[4,\infty)$ in the solution set of the inequality.
2. if $x \leq 3$ then $x < 4$ hence $f(x)=3-x-(4-x)=-1$ and we face $-1<x$ which is true for each $x$ with $-1<x\leq 3$. This shows $(-1,3]$ is also in the solution set of the inequality.
3. if $3<x<4$ then $f(x) = x-3-(4-x)=2x-7$. Hence in this context we must solve $2x-7<x$ which gives $x<7$ which is true for each $x$ in the interval considered. This places $(3,4)$ in the solution set of the inequality.

Put all of this together, we obtain $(-1,3] \cup (3,4) \cup [4,\infty) = (-1, \infty)$ which is your answer. Usually I solve this sort of thing with a sign-chart method.

Answer (score 7):

The standard semi-mechanical way to eliminate the absolute value signs is to divide the number line into segments. The critical point for $|x-4|$ is at $x=4$, and the critical point for $|x-3|$ is at $x=3$.

Suppose first that $x \ge 4$. Then $|x-4|=x-4$ and $|x-3|=x-3$. So we are looking at the inequality $(x-3)-(x-4)\lt x$, that is, at $1\lt x$, which is certainly true for $x\ge 4$.

Now suppose that $3\le x\lt 4$. Then $|x-4|=4-x$ and $|x=3|=x-3$, so we are looking at the inequality $(x-3)-(4-x)\lt x$, that is, $2x-7\lt x$. This simplifies to $x\lt 7$, which is certainly **true** in the interval $[3,4)$.

It is probably at this point that your calculation went astray. We were looking at the interval $[3,4)$ and asking which points **in this interval** satisfied our inequality. The manipulation told us that it was all points in this interval that satisfied $x\lt 7$. Well, they all do!

Finally, suppose that $x\lt 3$. Then $|x-4|=4-x$ and $|x-3|=3-x$. So we are looking at the inequality $(3-x)-(4-x)\lt x$. Calculate. The left side is $-1$, so for in the interval $(-\infty,3)$, the inequality holds precisely when $-1\lt x$.

Putting things together, we conclude that the original inequality holds (i) if $x\ge 4$; (ii) if $3\le x\lt 4$; and (ii) if $x\lt 3$ but $-1\lt x$. 
This complicated set of conditions can be summarized much more simply as $x\gt -1$.

There are other ways to describe the set of solutions. For example we could say that the set is $(-1,\infty)$.

Comment: You had me at "which simplifies to -1<x", I don't know how you concluded the original equality holds -1<x. Because I already found the answers to the intervals you suggested, but I don't know how those three answers give away that the one and only answer is -1<x

Comment: @user38807: I have added a lot more explanation. Hope it will do the job.

Comment: I already got another simpler answer that totally made me understand, but I surely appreciate the effort you did, and forgive me for being that dumb that I couldn't understand your answer. It's really late here, maybe I should get some sleep already.

Comment: @user38807: While you are examining a particular interval, you are interested in what conditions your inequality imposes on numbers *in that interval*. So you proceed systematically, one interval at a time. I suggest you look at the wording used by James S. Cook (final paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

If $x\ge4$, then $|x-3|=x-3$ and $|x-4|=x-4$, so you want $(x-3)-(x-4)\lt x$, which you should be able to solve (remembering to check your solution against the assumption $x\ge4$.

If $3\le x\le4$, then $|x-3|=x-3$ and $|x-4|=4-x$, so you get ....

If $x\le3$, then $|x-3|=\dots$

Answer (score 0):

$|x-3|-|x-4|< x$, I write in $|x-3|< x+|x-4|$

but remember: $|r|< s \implies   -s < r < s$.

So I write the equation in the form: $-x-|x-4| < x-3 < x+|x-4|$.

From this inequality I obtain 2 equations:

(a)  $-x-|x-4| < x-3$

(b) $x-3 < x+|x-4|$.

Remember too :  $|r| > s \implies  r > s \text{ or } r < -s $.

So this concept I will apply to equation (a) and equation (b).

From equation (a):

$-x-|x-4| < x-3$ I write so absolute value is in one side: -|x-4| < 2x-3 then I multiply by -1 : |x-4| > -2x+3 . Now I write the equation in the form of:  |r| > s---->  r > s OR r < -s .As a result we obtain 2 additional equation: x-4 > -2x+3 OR x-4 < 2x-3 . From the first one: 3x > 7  --->x > 7/3 or (7/3,∞) . From the second inequality: -1 < x  or (-1,∞) .The first and second inequality are OR function then: (7/3,∞) U (-1,∞) is: (-1,∞)

Now the equation (b): x-3 < x+|x-4| we write to put absolute value in one side:   $-3 < |x-4|$ or    $|x-4| > -3$ . To satisfy this inequality $x$ will take any value positive or negative. As a result we can write the result the value of $x$ for equation (b) as: $(-∞,+∞)$

The final result from the equation (a) AND (b) will be the intersection of their value: $(a)∩(b)$ or $(-1,∞)∩(-∞,∞)$ and find the final result for $x: (-1,∞)$ that satisfy the inequality $|x-3|-|x-4| < x$

Answer (score 0):

for /x-3/-/x-4/

1st if both absolute values are positive.
x=+1

2nd if both are negative, x=-1

3rd if the 1st one is negative and 2nd one positive x=7/3

4th if 1st one is posit. and 2nd one negat. x=7. 
so bcse all these numbers, give us a solution except -1 that is why all numbers above -1 are included in the solution. or S= x>-1. or from -1 to infinite.