# Solving inequalities with absolut values

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have this problem:

**Find the numbers x ∈ ℝ such that**:

|x + 1| + |x - 4| > 7

I have already checked when both of the absolute values change its sign, but I don't know how to continue. My last step was:

x + 1 if x ≥ -1 // -x -1 if x < -1 // x-4 if x ≥ 4 // -x -4 if x<4

Comment: Similar to this equation can be found in this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187343/inequality-with-two-absolute-values?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x\ge 4$. This means neither $x+1$ nor $x-4$ are negative, so the inequality becomes $$x+1+x-4> 7$$, which simplifies to $2x\ge10$, and $x\ge 5$. So the inequality holds when $x> 5$.

Suppose $-1\le x<4$, so $x+1\ge 0$, but $x-4<0$. The inequality becomes 
$$x+1-x+4> 7$$
which simplifies to $5> 7$ and that's obviously not true.

Suppose $x<-1$. This means both $x+1$ and $x-4$ are negative, so the inequality becomes:
$$-x-1-x+4> 7$$
Which simplifies to $-2x> 4$, so $x< -2$.

We conclude the inequality holds for all $x> 5$ and all $x< -2$

Comment: $x = 5$ and $x = -2$ does not work, so they should be strict inequalities.

Comment: I do not understand why in the last inequality you put a ≥ since in the previous line the inequation you show is with >

Comment: @Laura my mistake. I'll edit

Comment: Now I know how to do it. Thank you! @Mastrem

Comment: @Laura you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

1. $x < -1$. $-x - 1 + 4 - x > 7 \implies 3 - 2x > 7 \implies x < -2$.
2. $x = -1$ not feasible
3. $x > -1, x < 4$. $x + 1 + 4 - x > 7$ not feasible.
4. $x = 4$ not feasible
5. $x > 4$. $x + 1 + x - 4 > 7 \implies 2x - 3 > 7 \implies x > 5$.

Thus we have $x \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (5, \infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to look at this with cases.  Organizing the cases a bit better we have that:

$$|x+1|+|x-4|=\begin{cases}x+1+x-4&\text{if}~x\geq 4\\x+1-(x-4)&\text{if}~-1\leq x<4\\ -(x+1)-(x-4)&\text{if}~x<-1\end{cases}$$

Simplifying:

$$|x+1|+|x-4|=\begin{cases}2x-3&\text{if}~x\geq 4\\5&\text{if}~-1\leq x<4\\ -2x+3&\text{if}~x<-1\end{cases}$$

Now, look at each of these cases individually and when they are or aren't greater than $7$.

Comment: It has been really useful. Thank you!