# Elementary Method for Solving Equations Involving Multiple Absolute Values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose one has an equation in one unknown that has three or more absolute value signs such as $$
|ax + b| + |cx + d| + |ex + f| = gx + h
$$
Without invoking sophisticated techniques such as the CAD algorithm described in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-equation-involving-multiple-absolute-values), is there an elementary approach other than case-by-case analysis that will yield a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case-by-case method (with 4 cases, [as I discussed in my answer in the question to which you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3154/72)) is the only approach to solving such an equation that I've ever seen within the context of pre-college mathematics.

Comment: Maybe I could have been clearer; By an "elementary approach", I'm not ruling out, for example, Calculus or abstract algebra.