# How to determine different absolute value equation cases?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

This is a question from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896917/).

From:
$$
|3x|=\left\{ \begin{align}
3x & \text{   , if }x\geq 0 \\
-3x & \text{   , if }x <0 
\end{align}
\right\}
$$
$$
|4x+1|=\left\{ \begin{align}
4x+1 & \text{   , if }x\geq \frac{-1}{4} \\
-(4x+1) & \text{   , if }x <\frac{-1}{4}
\end{align}
\right\}
$$

How do you determine the different cases to check?

How do you get these as the cases: $x<\frac{-1}{4}$, $\frac{-1}{4}\leq x <0$, and $x\geq 0$?

Comment: How do you get the case: −1/4 ≤ x < 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve $|4x+1|\lt |3x|$ in the link, then note that
$$4x+1=0\iff x=-\frac 14,\ \ \ \ 3x=0\iff x=0.$$

Then, we can separate it into three cases :

For $x\lt -\frac 14$, then $|4x+1|=-(4x+1)$ and $|x|=-x$.

For $-\frac 14\le x\lt 0$, then $|4x+1|=4x+1$ and $|x|=-x$.

For $x\ge 0$, then $|4x+1|=4x+1$ and $|x|=x$.

Comment: @AppXene: I understand what your question is. I rewrite my answer. Take a look.

Comment: @AppXene: Imagine the number line. We have two points $x=-1/4$ and $x=0$ as I wrote in my answer. So, the number line can be separated into three parts, which are $x\lt -1/4, -1/4\le x\lt 0,0\le x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider that:$$ x<−\frac{1}{4} \iff 4x< -1 \iff 4x +1 < 0$$
$$ x\ge-\frac{1}{4} \iff 4x\ge -1 \iff 4x +1 \ge 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know that $$
|x|=\left\{ \begin{align}
x & \text{   , if }x\geq 0 \\
-x & \text{   , if }x <0 
\end{align}
\right\}.$$

Then, it must also be true that $$
|f(x)|=\left\{ \begin{align}
f(x) & \text{   , if }f(x) \geq 0 \\
-f(x) & \text{   , if }f(x) <0 
\end{align}
\right\}.$$

Substituting in for $f(x)$ and solving for the variable $x$ produces the desired result.