# Solving inequalities on both sides with complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I need to sketch this region $\left \{ z\in\mathbb{C}| |z-i|\leq |z-1| \right \}$. I'd like some assistance with solving this inequality because I think that's where I'm going wrong.

To solve the inequality I'm squaring both sides and trying to solve for that. Similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896917/how-to-solve-inequalities-with-absolute-values-on-both-sides).
$$(z-i)^2 \leq (z-1)^2$$
$$0\leq (z-1)^2 - (z-i)^2$$
$$0\leq ((z-1) - (z-i)) ((z-1) + (z-i))$$
$$0\leq (-1+i)(2z-1-i)$$
$$0\leq -2z+2zi+-i^2+1$$

Here is the point where I get stuck. I'm not quite sure how to progress from here.

Comment: Your first inequality's already wrong. We're dealing here with *complex* numbers, so their module is *not* to be taken as in the real case. It could help you to remeber this to take into account that in the complex plane the  is **no** linear order: no complex number is greater than or smaller than any other.

Comment: Note that $$i^2=-1.$$ But $$|i|^2=1.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

note that : $z=x+iy \rightarrow \space |z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ $$|z-i|<|z-1|\\$$put   $z=x+iy$ $$ |x+iy-i|<|x+iy-1|\\|x+i(y-1)|<|(x-1)+iy|\\\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}<\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$ now go on 
when you simplify 
$$x^2+(y-1)^2 <(x-1)^2+y^2\\-2y<-2x\\2x<2y\\x<y$$[image]

Comment: You should allow for equality as well.

Answer (score 5):

The geometric interpretation of your inequality is:

> The distance from $z$ to $i$ is less than or equal to the distance from $z$ to $1$.

Draw the perpendicular bisector to the segment from $1$ to $i$ and think about what this means.