# How to solve an inequality with absolute values on both sides?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have the following inequality:

$$|x+3| \geq |x-1| $$

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/896927/364241) I get:

$$
|x+3|=\left\{ \begin{align}
x+3 & \text{   , if }x\geq -3 \\
-x-3 & \text{   , if }x <-3 
\end{align}
\right\}
$$

$$
|x-1|=\left\{ \begin{align}
x-1 & \text{   , if }x\geq 1 \\
-x+1 & \text{   , if }x < 1 
\end{align}
\right\}
$$

Putting those together I get 3 sets of equations:

For $x<-3$:

$$-x-3\ge-x+1$$

For $-3 \le x< 1$:

$$x+3\ge-x+1$$

For $x\ge1$:

$$x+3\ge x-1$$

The first inequality however gives me:

$$-3 \ge 1$$

What am I doing wrong here? The answer to the problem is $x \ge -1$ by the way.

Comment: the second case give us $x\geq -1$, that is $-1\leq x \ <1$.

Comment: Coming up with one impossible range of 4 possible simply means that range is impossible and the solution must lie elsewhere.  It's exactly like this.  Suppose $\frac 1b (b+2)=0$.  Either $1/b =0$ or (b+2)=0.  But $1/b = 0$ is impossible.  So.... it isn't possible.  and I only consider the other one.  They aren't ALL true.  So showing one is impossible is not a contradiction or a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong. Getting $-3\ge 1$ in the first case means that the first case cannot occur, so there is no solution in the interval $(-\infty, -3)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you, so the only solution would be the second inequality, 2x >= -2 -> x >=1.

Comment: From the second inequality you get $-1\leq x<1$. (Remember you're in the case $-3\leq x<1$.) The third inequality $3\geq -1$ is always true, so you get $1\leq x$. Combining the two cases gives $-1\leq x$.

Comment: OP.  Also the last one gives you the pointless 3>= -1.  That simple means x >= 1 is not impossible.  (Doesn't mean it is true though).

Comment: @fleablood Why would it not mean that it is true?

Comment: It means that it *could* be true.  But it might not be.

Comment: @fleablood Fine, you mean we need to "check the answer".

Comment: @pi66 I don't understand why I'd get $-1 \le x < 1$? $ x+3 \ge −x+1$ -> $2x \ge -2$ -> $x \ge -1$? Since the other 2 equations don't give moe any solutions this is the answer, no? Could you explain with a little more detail?

Comment: It's because for the second inequality ($x+3\geq -x+1$), you assumed that $-3\leq x<1$. So when you conclude the possible values of $x$, you should take into account this constraint.

Comment: @pi66 I see, thank you for the answer

Comment: As it turns out that's an unnecessary restraint we get **IF** $x \le 1$ then $x \in [-1,1]$ and **IF** $x > 1$ then $x \in (1, \infty)$.  So we conclude $x \in [-1,1]\cup (1,\infty)= [-1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

As you are no doubt aware, the first statement leads to no solution, the second gives you the solution, and the third, being a statement of fact, does not contradict that, so you do arrive at the correct answer.

As a matter of practicality, however, it would be easier to solve the inequality by solving $$(x+3)^2\geq(x-1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong.  You just misinterpreted what you were trying to do and what the information tells you:

You have 3 ranges to consider and in each range you have a set of inequalities to interpret.

If $x \le -3$ (which it might or might not be).

We have $-x - 3 \ge -x + 1$ so $-3 \ge 1$.  This is impossible so this is not an option.

So we know $x > -3$.

If $-3 < x \le 1$ (which it might or might not be).

We have $x + 3 \ge -x + 1$ so $x \ge -1$.

So if $-3< x \le 1 \implies x \ge -1 \implies -1 \le x \le 1$.  **IF** $-3 < x \le -1$ which it might or might not be.

And if $x > 1$ (which it might or might not be)

We have $x + 3 \ge x -1$ so $3 \ge -1$ which is trivially true.

So if $x > 1$ then SOMETHING TRUE.  So $x > 1$ is possible.  But it might or might not be true.  But it's possible and if it is true ... we conclude nothing further.

Putting those together we conclude:

$-1 \le x \le 1$  **OR** $x > 1$ or

$x \in [-1,1] \cup [1,\infty) = [-1,\infty)$ or

$x \ge -1$.

.....

But another way, maybe better, to do it is:

$|x+3| \geq |x-1|$

$-|x+3| \le x-1 \le |x+3|$

$\min(x+3,-x-3) \le x-1 \le \max (x+3, -x - 3)$

$\min(x+4, -x -2) \le x \le \max (x+4, -x-2)$

So either $x+4 \le x \le -x-2$ or $-x-2 \le x \le x+4$.

The first one is clearly impossible so

$-x -2 \le x \le x+4$ ($x \le x + 4$ is redundant.)

so $-x-2 \le x$ so $x \ge -1$.

.....

I don't know.  Maybe that is harder.

====

Oh.

David Quinn offers a third option that is probably the easiest to solve, although intuitively I would have assumed it'd give the *most* extraneous impossible ranges.  As it turns out, it gives the *least*.

$|x + 3| \ge |x-1|$

$(x+3)^2 \ge (x-1)^2$

$x^2 + 6x + 9 \ge x^2 - 2x + 1$

$6x + 9 \ge -2x + 1$

which will give one and only one unambiguous solution range.

Comment: So we go from three cases to check (1 impossible, the other two mergeable) to two cases to check (1 impossible) to only one case.