# A general method for solving inequations with absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I've been asked to find which $b$ satisfy $|a + b| = |a| + |b|$ for $a \geq 0$. I'm familiar with the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-equation-involving-multiple-absolute-values/3154#3154) and I tried to apply it but I'm confused about what I should do with the solutions of each equation. Any leads?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* As both sides are non-negative,

$$|a + b| = |a| + |b| \ \ \text{ if and only if } \ \ |a+b|^2 = (|a| + |b|)^2$$

The right-hand side in turn is equivalent to $$a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = |a|^2 + 2|a||b| + |b|^2$$ Simplify that expression and you'll find a condition on $b$. Note that there are two cases: $a = 0$ and $a > 0$.

When you've found those conditions, think about what they mean geometrically on the number line.